# Create an ETL with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: etl, sql-server-2008r2-express

I've recently installed the latest version of SQL Server (2008 R2 x64) and I'm now trying get my first steps to create an ETL.

Is it possible to create an ETL with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, and if not is there some tool that provides that for free?

What I plan to do is collect data from multiple sources like a web services, rss feeds, a parsed url request, a file or maybe other database engine. Transform this collected data for an understandable schema (for my purposes) and store this in my SQL Server database.

Comment: ETL is a very generic term. Please state more clearly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what i pretend is collect data from multiple sources like a webservice, rss feed, a parsed url request, a file or maybe other database engine. Transform this collected data for an understandable schema (for my purposes) and store this on my datatabase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a rather simple, yet very flexible and more code-based approach as an alternative to the SSIS (Integration Services), I'd recommend you have a good look at the `Rhino ETL` code library by Ayende Rahien.

Check out these resources:

- [Rhino ETL 2.0](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/01/16/Rhino-ETL-2.0.aspx)
- [Object-oriented ETL using Rhino ETL](http://www.codinginstinct.com/2008/12/object-oriented-etl-using-rhinoetl.html)
- [Write ETL jobs in pure C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ETLWithCSharp.aspx?msg=3029625)

Rhino ETL is a code-based, programmer-oriented approach - it gives you nice, usable base classes, from which you can inherit and do just about anything - with very little effort.

Answer (score 0):

Integration Services, which is the product of SQLSERVER for this kind of tasks is not supported by the Express Edition.

Although, you can take the long way of making the integrations using plain TSQL and features of Express Edition like linked server (for other databases, access and excel), sqlcmd (for file system) and XML support(for web services).