# Sql update command with optional parameters?

Tags: c#, sql

I am inserting circa 500 000 objects into database, where many of them are same (have same primary key representation in database), but other fields might be different so I am using approach "update - if no rows affected - insert". The problem is that sometimes an object has some field set to null (unreadable from file) and is already in database with some value set, thus I update it to null = erase it .) How would implement scenario, that you would update only fields that are not null?

Here is a simple example of how I am doing it now:

```
private const string UpdateKun = "UPDATE pde.Kun SET Jmeno=@Jmeno WHERE Licence=@Licence";
private const string InsertKun = "INSERT INTO pde.Kun ([Licence], [Jmeno], [VykonnostniStupen]) VALUES (@Licence, @Jmeno, @VykonnostniStupen)";

var cmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateKun, conn, tran);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Licence", kun.Licence);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jmeno", kun.Jmeno);
RepairNulls(cmd.Parameters);
if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0) return;

cmd = new SqlCommand(InsertKun, conn, tran);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Licence", kun.Licence);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Jmeno", kun.Jmeno);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VykonnostniStupen", 0);
RepairNulls(cmd.Parameters);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


private void RepairNulls(SqlParameterCollection col)
    {
        foreach (SqlParameter param in col.Cast<SqlParameter>().Where(param =>  param.Value == null))
        {
            param.Value = DBNull.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some SQL products have functionality as you describe with one statement: `INSERT ... IF DUPLICATE UPDATE ...`

Comment: @ypercube since its a `SqlCommand` its SQL Server.  Then it would be MERGE as long as it 2005 or greater

Comment: Yeah I am not really into sql, but I would assume it should have that functionality :) I use Sql server 2008, express edition, I will lookup the MERGE syntax, thanks

Comment: Check also this answer: [Create an ETL with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523368/create-an-etl-with-sql-server-2008-r2-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the Update to:

```
UPDATE pde.Kun 
SET Jmeno=@Jmeno 
WHERE Licence=@Licence
  AND @Jmeno IS NOT NULL
```

If you have more than one columns to update:

```
UPDATE pde.Kun 
SET Jmeno = COALESCE(@Jmeno, Jmeno)
  , ColumnB = COALESCE(@ColumnB, ColumnB) 
WHERE Licence=@Licence
```

Comment: Good idea, seems like solution even thought I am little bit afraid of performance, cuz this was just example of an object, usually objects I am inserting have like 20 fields and all can be null in database, except the primary key ofcourse.

Comment: Using the `COALESCE()` functions would not a performance problem, I think. Using 500K Updates and 500K Inserts for inserting 500K rows might be though.

Comment: Depending on your DBMS (SQL-Server? what version?), you may have better choices thna inserting/updating rows, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't update the database just for checking if the row exists

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pde.Kun WHERE Licence=@Licence
```

and just check if the returned value is greater then 0

Comment: Well in situation where you want insert a row and if the row already exits then update it, with my approach you save one sql call (try update, if it doesnt affect any row insert it, this is max 2 calls, usually just 1 because there is high repetition in my case and the update succedes), if I'd use select count to find if it exists I would have to do allways 2 calls, find if it exists, then update or insert

Comment: But you are not updating the rows with identical data. The select statement is much better performance wise since it is using the table's index to find out if that row exists. [Similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696063/select-vs-update-performance-with-index) should help