# How to write update query in c# for the insert code below

Tags: c#, sql-server

CS Code

```
int hrd1 = bl.BL_INSERT_HR_UPLOAD(FORM_ID, OFFER_ID, DOJ, NI_NUMBER, EMP_ID);
```

Business Layer

```
public int BL_INSERT_HR_UPLOAD(string FORM_ID,string OFFER_ID,string DOJ,string NI_NUMBER,string    EMP_ID)
{
   int hrd1 =dl.DL_INSERT_HR_UPLOAD
   (FORM_ID,OFFER_ID,DOJ,NI_NUMBER,EMP_ID);
   return hrd1;
}
```

Data Layer

```
public int DL_INSERT_HR_UPLOAD(string FORM_ID, string OFFER_ID, string DOJ, string NI_NUMBER, string EMP_ID)
{
        con.Close();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT_HR_DOCUMENT_UPLOAD", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FORM_ID", FORM_ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OFFER_ID", OFFER_ID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ABSOLUTE_DOJ", DOJ);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NI_NUMBER",NI_NUMBER);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEE_NUMBER", EMP_ID);

        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Could you please let me know to write update DB query, so it looks and works the same way the insert code mentioned above. FYI - form_id,offer_id is FK,PK.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Only copying existing code does not show any effort...

Comment: The problem is that the stored procedure could touch any number of tables.  There are [lots](http://forums.asp.net/t/1033837.aspx) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246182/sql-update-statement-in-c-sharp) [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8995754/sql-update-command-with-optional-parameters) of how to do sql updates with parameters.  But your problem is larger.  You must deconstruct the stored proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

```
UPDATE HR_TBALE set OFFER_ID=@OFFER_ID,DOJ=@ABSOLUTE_DOJ,NI_NUMBER=@NI_NUMBER,EMP_ID=@EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
WHERE FORM_ID=@FORM_ID
```